# Android launch mediplayer for videos from a webview?

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview, if the user clicks on a link, it opens in the same webview (I controll that with shouldOverrideUrlLoading()) but if it is a video link (mp4, 3gp) it does not launch the media player to reproduce the video (as it does in the normal browser app).
How o force the media player to launch when a video link is clicked inside a webview?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "if it is a video link (mp4, 3gp) it does not launch the media player to reproduce the video"? Do you mean that you are not called with `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` for such URLs?

Answer (score 4):

In this case you will need to execute an Intent to load an external video url.
This also conveniently allows user to return to the previous view ( activity )  without any problem. See code below....

```
 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 *  WebViewClientHandler() allows for overriding default phone web browser so we can load in gui
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
private class WebViewClientHandler extends WebViewClient {
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://YOUTSTREAM.FLV");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

    startActivity(intent);
        return true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably irrelevant now, but what you see is in the browser is not the media player, but an Android owned VideoView. When a video link is clicked a call to `onShowCustomView (View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)` in WebChromeClient is made. It's the application obligation to display that view and then inform the WebView that the View is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

I meant that when the url is pointing to a video file, I'd like the mediaplayer to reproduces it. Every other URL is being handled by the webview, and that is OK but when the URL is pointing to a video file, nothing happens when I try to load that url.

Answer (score 1):

you should try this

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.embeddedWebView);
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
    {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long size)
        {
            Intent viewIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            viewIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), mimeType);

            try
            {
                startActivity(viewIntent);
            }
            catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                Log.w("YourLogTag", "Couldn't find activity to view mimetype: " + mimeType);
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, as far as I know, Android supports rtsp playback only. So onclick of the link, give document.location.href="rtsp://your video url";