# webview video in Android not working and has no errors

Tags: android, video, webview

No errors found but not working anyway:

```
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    if (url.endsWith(".mp4") || url.endsWith(".3gp") || url.endsWith(".m4v") || url.endsWith(".mov")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(url), "video/*");
                        Log.d(TAG, "Play Media");
                        Uri tempPath = Uri.parse(url);
                        MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(RunHTML5WebView.this, tempPath);
                        player.start();
                        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);   
                        startActivity(intent);
                        return true;
                }
                    else{
                        return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2299994/android-launch-mediplayer-for-videos-from-a-webview)

Comment: that would work for a fixed url. My webview has multiple video's that change weekly so I would need the webview to handle all video tags in what ever URL is available from the mobile site.